# finding bad characters in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, sql-server-2016, collate

I have a table in my database where some of the data for the column "customer name" has been updated as invalid or Spanish characters as below.

```
Ana MartÃnez
Â Ann  Harms
Â Don  Bergh
Maria Muñoz
```

I want to find the list of customername which has these kind of invalid or Spanish characters. Can we write a query to identify these?if yes, please assist.

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Did these characters appear due to the database columns not being in UTF-8 formats? If so, once solved, I suggest you alter your relevant tables to use utf8_general_ci.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jgdoncel/bc20b39b8cd612c4a26dfcaf3bb14dd8 this function remove accents but unfortunately in mysql code

Comment: actually I don't have write access to my database.but I wanted to find out the records which has these characters

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just list all names where unwanted charracter is inside. For this you would need all "bad" characters

```
select * from yourtable where customer_name like '%Ã%' or customer_name like '%ñ%'
```

Comment: Think he was just using those as examples. The scale might be much larger than just those 2 characters. It could be quite comprehensive.

Comment: hmm, yeah, ok but anyways the list of special characters shouldnt be that long as these as Spanish characters only (what i read in his question )

Comment: when I use this query I am not getting the examples I have mentioned in my question. the result has no rows

Comment: did you correctly update the column names and tablename?

Comment: Worth noting that if you have multiple special characters, it might be more convenient to make a *regexp* to handle the logic. It'll be a lot faster too.